# Java icmp4j multi-threaded ping not so mult-threaded

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code executes 254 ping requests against a /24 IP hostList, each in its own thread (Or that is what I thought). A full /24 subnet (172.21.0.0/24) is loaded into hostList and then passed to the worker in a for loop to kick of each thread to get the ping work done.

The timeout for each ping thread is 1000ms, so if 254 IP's are passed to 254 threads the complete process should not take more than one to two seconds.

i.e. I should be able to ping all the ip's in this /24 in under 2 seconds flat if the program is indeed multi-threaded.

The outcome seems to be pinging each host in series not in parallel... What am I doing wrong in terms of getting this to be a true multi-threaded ping application?

```
/*
 * Step 1: Ping a subnet to find alive hosts
 */
package smartsdiscoveryrobot;    

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;    

import org.icmp4j.IcmpPingUtil;
import org.icmp4j.IcmpPingRequest;
import org.icmp4j.IcmpPingResponse;    

import org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils; // Subnet Utils to genrate host list    

/**
 *
 * @author beukesmar
 */
public class PingExecutorService {    

    private static final String COMMUNITY       = "public";
    private static final int    NUMBEROFPINGS   = 1;
    private static final int    PINGTIMEOUT     = 1000;
    //Determine how many threads should be spawned by fetching the number of processors from Runtime
    //private static final int    NUM_THREADS     = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private static final int    NUM_THREADS     = 254; //Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();    

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Availabe threads: " + NUM_THREADS);
        // Instantitate new Fixed size thread pool with NUM_THREADS
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);    

        SubnetUtils utils = new SubnetUtils("172.21.0.1", "255.255.255.0");
        System.out.println("Low  Address: " + utils.getInfo().getLowAddress());
        System.out.println("High Address: " + utils.getInfo().getHighAddress());
        // Construct hostList with all IP's in above subnet
        String[] hostList = utils.getInfo().getAllAddresses();    

        // Create worker for each host in hostlist
        System.out.println("Host array length: " + hostList.length);
        for (String host : hostList) {
            Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(host, PINGTIMEOUT, COMMUNITY);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        // Wait until all threads are finish
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {    

        }
        System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");
    }    

    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {    

        private final String host;
        private final String community;
        private final int pingtimeout;    

        MyRunnable(String host, int pingtimeout, String community) {
            this.host = host;
            this.pingtimeout = pingtimeout;
            this.community = community;
        }    

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print("Spawning new thread to ping to host: " + host + " timeout=" + pingtimeout + "\n");    

            /*
            Code to perform ping
             */
            final IcmpPingRequest request = IcmpPingUtil.createIcmpPingRequest();
            request.setHost(host);
            request.setTimeout(pingtimeout);
            request.setPacketSize(32); // Send 32 bytes    

            // Perform NUMBEROFPINGS pings per host
            int numberofpings = NUMBEROFPINGS;
            int numberofsuccesspings = 0;
            int numberoffailedresponse = 0;
            int minlatency = 0;
            long avglatency = 0;
            int maxlatency = 0;
            int sumoflatency = 0;
            long totaltime = 0;
            boolean isalive = false;
            boolean haspacketloss = false;
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberofpings; i++) {
                final IcmpPingResponse response = IcmpPingUtil.executePingRequest(request);
                // host responded to a echo request
                if (response.getSuccessFlag() == true) {
                    isalive = true;
                    numberofsuccesspings++;
                    //System.out.println("Reply from " + host + " icmp_req=" + i + " bytes=" + response.getSize() + " time=" + response.getRtt() + "ms");
                    // Set inital values
                    if (minlatency == 0) {
                        minlatency = response.getRtt();
                        maxlatency = response.getRtt();
                    }
                    // Set minlatency if response latency is lower than minlatency
                    if (response.getRtt() < minlatency) {
                        minlatency = response.getRtt();
                    }
                    // Set maxlatency if response latency is higher than maxlatency
                    if (response.getRtt() > maxlatency) {
                        maxlatency = response.getRtt();
                    }
                    sumoflatency = sumoflatency + response.getRtt();
                    totaltime = totaltime + response.getDuration();
                    // host has dropped a echo request packet
                } else {
                    haspacketloss = true;
                    numberoffailedresponse++;
                    //System.out.println("Reply from " + host + ":Error:" + response.getErrorMessage());
                    totaltime = totaltime + response.getDuration();
                }    

                //final String formattedResponse = IcmpPingUtil.formatResponse(response);
                //System.out.println(host + ":" + formattedResponse);
            }    

            long packetloss = numberoffailedresponse / numberofpings * 100;
            // Dont devide by 0
            if (numberofsuccesspings != 0) {
                avglatency = sumoflatency / numberofsuccesspings;
            }    

            /*System.out.println(
                    "---" + host + " ping statistics ---\n"
                    + numberofpings + " packets transmitted, " + numberofsuccesspings + ", " + packetloss + "% packet loss, time " + totaltime + "ms\n"
                    + "rtt min/avg/max = " + minlatency + "/" + avglatency + "/" + maxlatency + " ms");*/
            System.out.println(host + " isalive=" + isalive + " haspacketloss=" + haspacketloss);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a fixed number of cores on your machine. That number is probably somewhere between 1 and 16 (depending on how you wan tto count "cores"); most likely 4 or 8 (again, depending). That's the maximum number of truly concurrent things you can have running on your CPU(s). If you want to interleave these more than that, you'll have to get into doing asynchronous I/O.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, a thread that is blocked in a system call, waiting for the reply to a ping does not count against the number of cores.  Threads have been around a lot longer than multi-core CPUs.  One of the main reasons why people started using them is because using different threads to make synchronous I/O calls on different files/devices/network ports can be easier to understand than doing asynchronous I/O calls.

Comment: @jameslarge: If it's a system call, yes. But there's a reason async I/O tends to perform better than multi-threaded sync I/O.

Comment: Cache coherence?  Cost of context switches?  Yeah, we often have to choose between simplicity and ultimate performance.  But even so, a thread that is waiting for an ICMP response is (hopefully!) not _running_.

Comment: Ok, so I am sticking to threads... not up for async I/O even if it will perform better. Is the code correct for the thread use case or is something obviously wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

icmp4j can't seem to ping in parallel, it does 1 ping at a time.

I'm not sure why, wild guess: might have something to do with jna.

My solution was to use processbuilder to execute native ping command.